# Android MMS Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mms

I am working on a MMS broadcast receiver. It already starts when receiving a MMS but I dont know how to capture / parse the contents of the mms like it is done with sms in this example:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        }
                        if (messages.length > -1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading a couple of related questions:

[Detecting new MMS (Android 2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056455/detecting-new-mms-android-2-1)
[Detecting MMS messages on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329819/detecting-mms-messages-on-android)

It seems this feautre is mostly supported, but not officially, so you wouldn't find much on the documentation. So, [one of the links](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/where-can-i-find-information-about-sending-receiving-mms-t51284.html) provided within those related questions points to something which looks like something you may be interested in.

Specially interesting this piece of code:

```
   public void startMMSMonitoring() {
      try {
         monitorStatus = false;
         if (!monitorStatus) {
            contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms"), true, mmsObserver);

            Uri uriMMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms");
            Cursor mmsCur = mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(uriMMSURI, null, "msg_box = 4", null, "_id");
            if (mmsCur != null && mmsCur.getCount() > 0) {
               mmsCount = mmsCur.getCount();
               Log("", "MMSMonitor :: Init MMSCount ==" + mmsCount);
            }
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log("", "MMSMonitor :: startMMSMonitoring Exception== "+ e.getMessage());
      }
   }
```

What if you have a look, test and give us some feedback?

regards.